# Where is the greeter npc?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I wanted to check out the [Guild Initiative Headquarters](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Initiative_Headquarters) today but I got this message when trying to enter. It's devilishly generic, so I'm really not sure what NPC to talk to.

[image: Guild HQ no-entry message]

Does anyone know what I need to do to 'unlock' the hq. I am a guild leader.

Comment: Pretty sure I just walked in, and only had to pick which of my guilds I wanted to represent. I agree, though, it's not very well explained. Have you tried talking to the NPCs just outside the headquarter building?

Comment: Yep, I chatted to Ember Doomforge (http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ember_Doomforge) with no luck. Which guild I represent also doesn't impact it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dulfy](http://dulfy.net/2015/10/23/gw2-guild-hall-claiming-and-upgrade-guide/) to the rescue:

> If you can’t enter the Initiative Headquarters because it says your
>   guild has been updated, talk to the Guild registrar outside.

So, try talking to the [Guild Registrar](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Registrar).

Comment: Worth noting that you have to be representing the guild you want to deal with when speaking to the NPC.